# Using Sessions with Java Sockets without SSL

Tags: java, sockets, session, ssl

I am suning SSLSockets in a Java application. I was wondering how much overhead the secure SSL connection produces and wanted to measure the traffic with and without using SSL.

I am using a SSLSession object to store the username into the session once he is logged in to avoid retransmitting the password with every message. As long as the session is valid, the user does not need to send the password with his messages.

Now I wanted to switch to an unsecure connection for a traffic comparison. It seems like there is no Session object in java.net.*. Is it impossible to have a Session without an SSL encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible. There are no TCP sessions. There are SSL Sessions, HTTP sessions, ...